# Object type CLanguage

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a vba script I found on the web.
However in the script, there is a declaration of a variable with object type "CLanguage", and I have not managed to find many examples of CLanguage type so far on the web.

This is part of the code(I got rid of code which does not seem to matter to identify what Clanguage is).

```
Dim clsLanguage As CLanguage

Set clsLanguage = New CLanguage

    DetectLanguage = clsLanguage.LanguageCode
```

You can see the full code on http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/03/15/language-detection/.

By reading comments, it seems CLanguage is a class the person who wrote the script had defined, and it seems his help is necessary to run this code.

Comment: CLanguage is a VBA class that Dick wrote (but didn't include in that post unfortunately). If you're lucky, since I know he's on here sometimes, he might see this and still have a copy. ;)

Comment: That explains why I could not find any info on the Web. I modified the question accordingly. Lets hope he will come by someday.

Answer (score 0):

The CLanguage is a VBA class, right click VBAProject to insert a "Class Module", and use the code in the link to implement the class.

The "DetectLanguage" is a function you can put in "Module", and others belongs to the CLanguage class.